# Auto fade in animation

Tags: jquery, html, animation, fadein

I'd like this code:

```
<section id="banner">
  <img src="images/logo-senca.png" width="600px" height="230px">
    <a href="mens.html">
      <div id="gumb" class="one-third column">
         <p><input type="submit" value="Nakupuj" class="carrot-flat-button"></p>
      </div>
    </a>
   </div> <!-- is this wrong? -->
</section>
```

to fade in or slide down as soon as the web page loads and I don't know how to do that in jquery, so any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

*Update*

Here's CSS for banner:

```
    #banner {
    background-attachment:  fixed;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    background-image:  url("images/bg.png");
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 6em 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Edited your HTML code and noted an extra `</div>` Marked in Question. Up to you to further edit my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the following piece of code from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354742/jquery-previous-html-element-still-showing-when-new-element-clicked/). Credits goes to whoever actually wrote it.  Hope it helps

```
$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function (easing, callback) {
 return this.animate({
    opacity: 'toggle',
    height: 'toggle'
 }, 'slow', easing, callback);
};

$('#banner').slideFadeToggle();
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2aLfL/5/)

*Updated*

```
$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function (speed, easing, callback) {
 speed = speed || 'slow';
 easing = easing || 'linear';

 return this.animate({
    opacity: 'toggle',
    height: 'toggle'
 }, speed, easing, callback);
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2aLfL/7/)

*Side note: you should first hide the element using `display:none` so that it'll fade in. If the element is visible, it'll fade out*

Comment: So I tried these codes u gave me. The  first one doesn't work in the actual document, the element simply doesn't show, then I tried it in the jsfiddle and there it slides away. The second code also doesn't work and just shows the element without any animation. Please help. Oh and in the question now I added CSS for banner.

Comment: @user3765322 you should first hide the element using 'display:none` if you want it to fade in [demo with updated css](http://jsfiddle.net/2aLfL/7/).Also, make sure you've added the function before you use it in your actual document... hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XBpmy/3

```
#banner p {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}
#banner p.load {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$("#banner p").addClass("load");
```

HTML:

```
<section id="banner">
    <p><img src="images/logo-senca.png" width="600px" height="230px" /></p> <a href="mens.html"><div id="gumb" class="one-third column">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Nakupuj" class="carrot-flat-button" /></p></div></a>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response, but this codes u gave me also doesn't work. Element doesn't show.