# Jquery previous .html() element still showing when new element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to write code which finds all anchors and attaches a function that displays a popup of the elements text.  My code is probably a mess, but I was able to get it working however the issue I have now is:

If I click link 1, then link 2, then click link 1 again, it displays link 2's text  however if i click it again it displays the correct text.

I am not sure exactly how to rewrite or go about fixing this code to properly display the element which is clicked, text all the time.

here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/2aLfL/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
});    
}

$(function() {
   $('a').click(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
     deselect($(this));

} else {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
    var elText = $(this).text();
    $('#elPop').html("<p>" + "<br><br>" + "You just clicked: <br><b>" + elText + "</b><br><br><br>" + "Click anywhere to Close" + "</p>");
    console.log(this);

    $("#closeWin").click(function () {
        $('.anchorpop').hide();
    });
}
return false;
});
});

    $(function close(){
 $(document).click(function(){  
  $('.anchorpop').hide();
  });
});


$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding the following click handler

```
    $("#closeWin").click(function () {
      $('.anchorpop').hide();
    });
```

inside `<a>` click handler so whenever a link is clicked, multiple handlers are being added.

You can avoid many unnecessary code using `toggleClass()` method.

You can also bind same event handlers to multiple elements by passing additional selectors.

after all your code boils down to

```
$(function () {
  $('a').click(function () {
    var htmlString = "<p>" + "<br><br>" + "You just clicked: <br><b>" + $(this).text() + "</b><br><br><br>" + "Click anywhere to Close" + "</p>"
    $('.pop').html(htmlString).slideFadeToggle(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
  return false;
  });
  $("#closeWin, .anchorpop").click(function () {
    $('.anchorpop').hide();
  });
});
```

and the custome `slideFadeToggle` function.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aLfL/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much this worked great, makes a lot more sense than my convoluted mess!